# typeof(T) versus o.GetType()

Tags: .net, performance, generics

For a method

```
public void Foo<T>(T o)
{
    var oType = o.GetType();
    var tType = typeof(T);
}
```

Is there anything I should consider when choosing which one to use, either functional or non-functional?

Answer from [Jon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/50079/jon) [below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28005628/442351).

I've created a fiddle to demonstrate it:

https://dotnetfiddle.net/Y4bAGf

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Of course: you should consider whether you want the resulting type to match the static or runtime type of the argument.

This may be the same type in your typical use case, but that cannot be taken for granted. For example:

```
Foo<object>(string.Empty); // oType = string, tType = object
```

Moreover, in the general case you have to be careful to not call 
`GetType` on `null`.

Comment: Just to clarify, `tType` is the dynamic typing, `oType` is the static typing?

Comment: @BanksySan: no, the other way around. Static type is what the compiler knows (T), runtime our dynamic type is whatever you might pass in (can be a type that did not even get written until after this code was compiled).